# ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor United - How to use Azure B2C?

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, .net-8.0

How do you configure a new .NET 8 Blazor united project to use Azure B2C for authentication?

I am not able to find any code samples, and what worked for ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor server-side does not appear to work in this new Blazor model in ASP.NET Core 8.

Comment: To be clear, you have a running .net core 7 app that works, but when you bring over the same code and settings it doesn't work? What doesn't work exactly? Are you using the same https localhost and/or is that port registered in B2C? Did you use the install template wizard for BLazor to attach to B2C and the code it placed didn't work?

Comment: I had all the same questions issues with Preview7, refer to this GitHub issue-- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48772  --It's possible with the release of RC1 today, this might be working now.  Seems there was a lot of Blazor work and changes, so perhaps try it now.

Comment: Also refer to this-- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48786, seems there may be some open items with RC1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ΩmegaMan and Brian for the comments.

> what worked for ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor server-side does not appear to work in this new Blazor model in ASP.NET Core 8.

I have tried to create Blazor Server App, but I didn't find the .NET 8 version in it.

To work with new Blazor United in ASP.NET Core 8, check the below steps.

***Create a new Blazor Web App with .NET 8.0 Preview version.***

[image]

- Add new project `Blazor WebAssembly App` with `.NET 8.0 Preview version` to the solution.

[image]

- Select the Authentication type as `Microsoft Identity Platform`.
  [image]
- To integrate Blazor Web Assembly into a Blazor United Project, we need to do few changes in the created Blazor WASM.

***In Blazor WebAssembly App***

- Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` NuGet Package.
- Add the reference of Blazor Web Assembly App to Blazor Web App.

Sample Blazor United App by [mkArtakMSFT](https://github.com/mkArtakMSFT/BlazorWasmClientInteractivity/tree/main/src)

> How do you configure a new .NET 8 Blazor united project to use Azure B2C for authentication?

- In the `Connected Services` add the `Microsoft Identity Platform`.

[image]

- Select the Correct Tenant ID related to Azure ADB2C, Create a new App.

[image]

- New app will be registered in the ADB2C tenant.
- Follow this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0) and configure the necessary permissions.

I can see the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0) with Version 8,
[image]

Even it is redirecting to the same .NET 7 version page.

Also refer [BlazorHelpWebsite](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/55) which has clear steps to configure B2C for older versions.